# hidden mongo collections - how to show all collections?

Tags: mongodb

What settings of mongo hide collections ?
I can see databases:

`show dbs`

but (after use `<db>`):

`db.printCollectionStats()`

or

`db.getCollectionNames()`

or

`show collections`

gives no results. no matter what mongo-client I used.
and yes - I have collections there and can access them directly like

`db.<collection>.<method>`

Comment: just because you can access them does not mean they exist, MongoDB does lazy creation and loading of collections and data

Comment: how about db.system.namespaces.find() or db.getCollectionInfos() if is version 3.0?

Comment: What mongo-clients are you using?

Comment: @Sammaye: as I wrote - I *can* access them, but I cannot listing them. I know document exists, because I can do any operation and everything work perfect except one single drawback - I need remember collection name.

Comment: @HaRLoFei: the same - empty result.

Comment: @Jaco: I have mongo 3.0.4.

Comment: do if you do `db.<collection>.find()` it shows documents?

Comment: As further explanation there is no such thing as hidden collections. Though auth might be hiding some stuff but since you can access the collection that shouldn't be doing anything. Technically MongoDB should not work if the namespaces collection is empty else it cannot keep track of the collection itself

Comment: It sounds like a permission issue, are you using authentication ? Also check out this bug report https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17529